# error while passing jvm argument from docker file

Tags: java, docker, jar

This is my Dockefile :

```
# Start with a base image containing Java runtime
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

# Add a volume pointing to /tmp
VOLUME /tmp

# Make port 8080 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 8080

# The application's jar file
COPY Server_Changes/glowroot  /tmp 
ARG JAR_FILE=target/websocket-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ARG OK=/tmp/glowroot.jar

# Add the application's jar to the container
ADD ${JAR_FILE} websocket-demo.jar

# Run the jar file 
ENTRYPOINT ["java", " -javaagent:/glowroot.jar" , "- Dglowroot.agent.id=Docker "," -jar /websocket-demo.jar"]
```

I am getting the following error when building the image:

> Could not find or load main class-javaagent:.glowroot.jar

can someone please explain why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the JSON-like syntax in `RUN`, `ENTRYPOINT`, and `CMD` commands, the spaces inside the quotes matter.  In particular, when you say

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java", " -javaagent:/glowroot.jar" , ...]
#                    ^
```

The space is part of the option; and since the option doesn't start with a `-`, Java interprets it as a class name.  This is basically true of all of your options.  In the final option, `-jar` and the class name are two separate options and need to be in two separate "words".

(Consider changing this `ENTRYPOINT` to a `CMD` to make the image easier to debug, and removing the `VOLUME` declaration; it will only cause unexpected odd side effects.)

```
CMD ["java", "-javaagent:/glowroot.jar",
     "-Dglowroot.agent.id=Docker",
     "-jar", "/websocket-demo.jar"]
```